# Ошибка LookupError и TypeError в AIOHTTP

Tags: python, aiohttp

world!
Пишу сайт на **Flask**, понадобилось на другой отправить аудиофайл .wav через AIOHTTP (а именно класс `MultipartWriter`). При отправке выдает 2 ошибки:

1. Довольно странная ошибка, нет даже Exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/aiohttp/multipart.py", line 800, in append
    payload = get_payload(obj, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/aiohttp/payload.py", line 71, in get_payload
    return PAYLOAD_REGISTRY.get(data, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/aiohttp/payload.py", line 118, in get
    raise LookupError()
aiohttp.payload.LookupError
```

2. **НО**, `During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:` (выдает вторую ошибку)

```
TypeError: Cannot create payload from <FileStorage: 'Rec-54-2021.02.17-09.06.40.wav' ('audio/wav')>
```

С чем это может быть связано и что можно сделать с этим?

Comment: Покажите код, который выдаёт ошибку

Comment: Ну и конечно же aiohttp ничего не знает ни про какой FileStorage и не умеет (и не должен уметь) с ним работать